# Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

This is with reference to the previous question I asked regarding the rock, paper, scissors game using Javascript. I have 3 separate images depicting rock, paper and scissors in my HTML and a start button. When I click the start button the `start.addEventListener` should fire and will set the user and computer points to 0. I have 3 separate functions- `rockFunc()` when the user clicks on the rock image, `paperFunc()` when the user clicks on the paper image and `scissorFunc()` when the user clicks on the scissor image. Each of these functions has a set of conditions. In the block of each if-else-if statement there is a call to the `finalDisplay()` function which displays the user and computer points. It should also display the computer's choice which is randomly generated from a list(`choiceList`). The issue here is that I'm getting an error whenever I'm trying to run the command `choiceDisplay.remove()` which states that the `choiceDisplay` variable is undefined. I've attached the Javascript and the HTML code below.

```js
const rock = document.getElementById('rock');
const scissor = document.getElementById('scissor');
const paper = document.getElementById('paper');
const start = document.getElementById('start')
const main = document.getElementById('main-container');

var userPoints, computerPoints;

var firstDisplay, choiceDisplay; // firstDisplay to display the user's and computer's points. 

// choiceDisplay to display what the computer has chosen

var choiceList = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissor']; //choiceList from which the computer gets a random choice

var computerChoice;

// when the user clicks on the start button
start.addEventListener('click', function() {
  userPoints = 0;
  computerPoints = 0;
  firstDisplay = document.createElement('div');
  const text = document.createTextNode(`Computer: ${computerPoints}  User: ${userPoints}`);
  firstDisplay.classList.add('displayinitial');
  firstDisplay.appendChild(text);
  main.appendChild(firstDisplay);

})

// function to take care of displaying the user's & computer's points, and to display the computer's choice
function finalDisplay(userPoints, computerPoints, computerChoice) {
  firstDisplay = document.createElement('div');
  const text = document.createTextNode(`Computer: ${computerPoints}  User: ${userPoints}`);
  firstDisplay.classList.add('displayinitial');
  firstDisplay.appendChild(text);
  main.appendChild(firstDisplay);
  choiceDisplay = document.createElement('div');
  const displayChoice = document.createTextNode(`Computer chose ${computerChoice} `);
  choiceDisplay.classList.add('finaldisplay');
  choiceDisplay.appendChild(displayChoice);
  main.appendChild(choiceDisplay);
  // firstDisplay.remove();
}

// if the user clicks on rock

function rockFunc() {

  computerChoice = choiceList[Math.floor(Math.random() * choiceList.length)];

  if (rock && computerChoice == 'scissor') {
    userPoints = userPoints + 1;
    firstDisplay.remove();
    choiceDisplay.remove();
    finalDisplay(userPoints, computerPoints, computerChoice);
  } else if (rock && computerChoice == 'paper') {
    computerPoints = computerPoints + 1;
    firstDisplay.remove();
    choiceDisplay.remove();
    finalDisplay(userPoints, computerPoints, computerChoice);
  } else {
    alert("Play Again");
    firstDisplay.remove();
    // choiceDisplay.remove();
    // finalDisplay(userPoints, computerPoints, computerChoice);
  }
}

// when user clicks on paper
function paperFunc() {
  computerChoice = choiceList[Math.floor(Math.random() * choiceList.length)];

  if (paper && computerChoice == 'rock') {
    userPoints = userPoints + 1;
    firstDisplay.remove();
    choiceDisplay.remove();
    finalDisplay(userPoints, computerPoints, computerChoice);
  } else if (paper && computerChoice == 'scissor') {
    computerPoints = computerPoints + 1;
    firstDisplay.remove();
    choiceDisplay.remove();
    finalDisplay(userPoints, computerPoints, computerChoice);
  } else {
    alert("Play Again");
    firstDisplay.remove();
    // choiceDisplay.remove();
    // finalDisplay(userPoints, computerPoints, computerChoice);
  }
}

// when user clicks on scissor

function scissorFunc() {

  computerChoice = choiceList[Math.floor(Math.random() * choiceList.length)];

  if (scissor && computerChoice == 'paper') {
    userPoints = userPoints + 1;
    firstDisplay.remove();
    choiceDisplay.remove();
    finalDisplay(userPoints, computerPoints, computerChoice);
  } else if (scissor && computerChoice == 'rock') {
    computerPoints = computerPoints + 1;
    firstDisplay.remove();
    choiceDisplay.remove();
    finalDisplay(userPoints, computerPoints, computerChoice);
  } else {
    alert("Play Again");
    firstDisplay.remove();
    // choiceDisplay.remove();
    // finalDisplay(userPoints, computerPoints, computerChoice);
  }
}

rock.addEventListener('click', function() {
  rockFunc();
})

scissor.addEventListener('click', function() {
  scissorFunc();
})

paper.addEventListener('click', function() {
  paperFunc();
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Rock,Paper,Scissors</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/rock-paper-scissors/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main-container" id="main-container">
    <div class="heading-content">
      <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors Game!</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="button">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="start">Start</button>
    </div>

    <div class="main-content">
      <img src="/rock-paper-scissors/images/rock.png" alt="rock" class="game" id="rock">
      <img src="/rock-paper-scissors/images/scissor.png" alt="Scissors" class="game" id="scissor">
      <img src="/rock-paper-scissors/images/paper.png" alt="paper" class="game" id="paper">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="/rock-paper-scissors/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You set `choiceDisplay` in the `finalDisplay()` function. But you don't call that function until after you try to remove `choiceDisplay`.

Comment: Why are you adding and removing the DIV? Just put the DIV in the HTML, and replace its contents with the current choice.

Comment: Okay, I corrected that but how do I accomplish what you've written in the second line.

Comment: Put `<div id="choiceDisplay"></div>` in the HTML.

Comment: Yes I've done that as well, but the content still stays on the page when I run the command `choiceDisplay.remove()` (without getting the error)

Comment: You should never remove it. If you don't want the user to see it, just set its display property to `none`.

Comment: Okay so, in general does that mean its not necessary to use `element.remove()` when the element is already defined?  Also, how do I reset the values when the user clicks on the button?

Comment: There's no general answer, it depends on the application. Adding and removing is typically right for dynamic lists, but for single elements you can just change the style to make it visible or invisible.

Comment: You reset the values simply by assigning to `innerText`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you do `choiceDisplay.remove()` before you call `finalDisplay()`, but that function is where you assign `choiceDisplay`.

But instead of adding and removing the DIV, just create it statically in the HTML, and update its contents.

```js
const rock = document.getElementById('rock');
const scissor = document.getElementById('scissor');
const paper = document.getElementById('paper');
const start = document.getElementById('start')
const main = document.getElementById('main-container');
const choiceDisplay = document.getElementById('choice-display');
const firstDisplay = document.getElementById('first-display');

var userPoints, computerPoints;

var choiceList = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissor']; //choiceList from which the computer gets a random choice

var computerChoice;

// when the user clicks on the start button
start.addEventListener('click', function() {
  userPoints = 0;
  computerPoints = 0;
  firstDisplay.classList.add('displayinitial');
  firstDisplay.innerText = `Computer: ${computerPoints}  User: ${userPoints}`;
})

// function to take care of displaying the user's & computer's points, and to display the computer's choice
function finalDisplay(userPoints, computerPoints, computerChoice) {
  firstDisplay.classList.add('displayinitial');
  firstDisplay.innerText = `Computer: ${computerPoints}  User: ${userPoints}`;
  const displayChoice = document.createTextNode(`Computer chose ${computerChoice} `);
  choiceDisplay.classList.add('finaldisplay');
  choiceDisplay.innerText = `Computer chose ${computerChoice} `;
}

// if the user clicks on rock

function rockFunc() {

  computerChoice = choiceList[Math.floor(Math.random() * choiceList.length)];

  if (rock && computerChoice == 'scissor') {
    userPoints = userPoints + 1;
    finalDisplay(userPoints, computerPoints, computerChoice);
  } else if (rock && computerChoice == 'paper') {
    computerPoints = computerPoints + 1;
    finalDisplay(userPoints, computerPoints, computerChoice);
  } else {
    alert("Play Again");
  }
}

// when user clicks on paper
function paperFunc() {
  computerChoice = choiceList[Math.floor(Math.random() * choiceList.length)];

  if (paper && computerChoice == 'rock') {
    userPoints = userPoints + 1;
    finalDisplay(userPoints, computerPoints, computerChoice);
  } else if (paper && computerChoice == 'scissor') {
    computerPoints = computerPoints + 1;
    finalDisplay(userPoints, computerPoints, computerChoice);
  } else {
    alert("Play Again");
  }
}

// when user clicks on scissor

function scissorFunc() {

  computerChoice = choiceList[Math.floor(Math.random() * choiceList.length)];

  if (scissor && computerChoice == 'paper') {
    userPoints = userPoints + 1;
    finalDisplay(userPoints, computerPoints, computerChoice);
  } else if (scissor && computerChoice == 'rock') {
    computerPoints = computerPoints + 1;
    finalDisplay(userPoints, computerPoints, computerChoice);
  } else {
    alert("Play Again");
  }
}

rock.addEventListener('click', function() {
  rockFunc();
})

scissor.addEventListener('click', function() {
  scissorFunc();
})

paper.addEventListener('click', function() {
  paperFunc();
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Rock,Paper,Scissors</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/rock-paper-scissors/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main-container" id="main-container">
    <div class="heading-content">
      <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors Game!</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="button">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="start">Start</button>
    </div>

    <div class="main-content">
      <img src="/rock-paper-scissors/images/rock.png" alt="rock" class="game" id="rock">
      <img src="/rock-paper-scissors/images/scissor.png" alt="Scissors" class="game" id="scissor">
      <img src="/rock-paper-scissors/images/paper.png" alt="paper" class="game" id="paper">
    </div>
    <div id="first-display"></div>
    <div id="choice-display"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="/rock-paper-scissors/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```